# Angularjs Indeterminate Checkbox Slow

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have indeterminate checkbox like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/cjwprostar/M4vGj/6/

It works, but it uses **$watch**.

```
scope.$watch(childList, function(newValue) {
            var hasChecked = false;
            var hasUnchecked = false;

            // Loop through the children
            angular.forEach(newValue, function(child) {
                if (child[property]) {
                    hasChecked = true;
                } else {
                    hasUnchecked = true;
                }
            });

            // Determine which state to put the checkbox in
            if (hasChecked && hasUnchecked) {
                element.prop('checked', false);
                element.prop('indeterminate', true);
                if (modelCtrl) {
                    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(false);
                }
            } else {
                element.prop('checked', hasChecked);
                element.prop('indeterminate', false);
                if (modelCtrl) {
                    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(hasChecked);
                }
            }
        }, true);
```

If i create this checkboxes in **ng-repeat it slows UI**.
Is it possible to rewrite this part of code, to **not use $watch**?
Thx for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about without `indeterminateCheckbox` directive ?

Remove the directive, then add a `ng-change` method to your second level(fruit) `checkbox` which ensure that all items are checked or not like

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="checkAllEaten(person.name)" data-ng-model="fruit.eaten">
```

In you controller

```
$scope.checkAllEaten = function (name) {
    var person = $scope.model.people.filter(function(p){
        return p.name === name;
    })[0];

    var result = person.fruits.reduce(function (p, c) {
        if (!p) return false;
        return c.eaten && true || false;
    }, true);

    person.allEaten = result;        
};

//initialization
$scope.model.people.forEach(function(item){
    $scope.checkAllEaten(item.name);
});
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lo99vzj6/2/)